# Dragula not sending AJAX request

Tags: ajax, dragula

I am using the following code to sort the rows of a table based on Ids. I am using Dragula for drag and drop functionality. The Sorted Ids is presented in the variable sortedIDs. The alert present within if(sortedIDs) is showing an alert, but no request is being sent using AJAX.

```
 var container = document.getElementById('tb');
        var rows = container.children;
        var nodeListForEach = function (array, callback, scope) {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                callback.call(scope, i, array[i]);

            }
        };
        var sortableTable = dragula([container]);
        var pingu='';
        sortableTable.on('dragend', function() {
            nodeListForEach(rows, function (index, row) {
                //alert(row.id);
                pingu=pingu+','+row.id;
                //alert(pingu);
                // row.lastElementChild.textContent = index + 1;
                // row.dataset.rowPosition = index + 1;
            });
            var sortedIDs=pingu;
            pingu='';
           // alert (sortedIDs);


            if (sortedIDs) {
                 alert(sortedIDs);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '<?php echo $site_url . 'index.php/API/p2376ghDSPOLWYBdhBT'?>',
                    data: 'lmqSPOEhyVt87H6tBYSfdreg=' + sortedIDs + '&hjhqweuty87685gh87GCfsc6HF=' + sbds98JWUDGHKJ98yujg,
                    success: function (tata) {
                        alert (tata);
                        if (tata == '1') {
                            $("#success").show();
                            $('#success').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
                        } else {
                            $("#failure").show();
                            $('#failure').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
                        }
                    }


                });
            } else {
                //$('#ms').html('<option value="">Select Q level first</option>');
            }







        });
```

And when i am adding

```
error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

}
```

for showing AJAX error, it starts throwing the alert too.

Any sort of help would be deeply appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I forgot to retrieve the value of an attribute and send it to the API.

```
var sbds98JWUDGHKJ98yujg = $('#p2JMopns3hfBubNNHJeer').val();
```